# Is there a way to pass JavaScript function call answer to a PHP variable to be used in the same page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I would like to get the option value from a HTML select tag and pass it into a PHP variable.

I am able to do this in a JavaScript function, however, I would like to use this variable elsewhere in the script.

This is the select tag code:

```
   <select id="languageselector" onChange='showSelected(this.value)'>
    <option value="">Pick A language</option>
    @foreach($reviewForm_language as $lang)
     <option value="{{$lang->id}}">{{$lang->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
```

This is the JavaScript code to get the selected value;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showSelected(val)
    {
       document.getElementById('selectedResult').innerHTML =  val;
       return val
    }
</script>
```

To display the selected value I call and works well as required.

```
<div id='selectedResult'></div>
```

I would like to pass this answer `<div id='selectedResult'></div>` to a PHP variable in the same page without reloading.

Anyone assist, thank you.

Comment: you should use Ajax to communicate with the server (PHP) and not have your page reload.

Comment: Where's the rest of your form? If you POST the form you can retrieve the value on the next page with `<?php $formvalue = $_POST["whatever_you_used_for_your_form_field_name"]; ?>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need ajax() for that

javascript:

```
function updateTab(value){
   $.ajax({
      url  : "<php page>",
      type : "post",
      data : {data : value},
      success : function(){
        alert("Sent!");
     }
  });
}
```

PHP:

```
$getValue = $_POST["data"];
// do something here....
```